# Node-Red Telegram chat through two bots

Tags: telegram-bot, node-red

I want to design a chat system through Node-Red that two Telegram bots which in one side there is an operator who has the other side's Telegram user ID. I designed it so it asks for user ID, then asks for message, and sends it to the other bot, and the other person only can write to the operator, but it does not work.
Well, I do not know how to transfer one variable from one node to the other without making it global.
Can you help me?

Comment: Dear Aamirza, providing a bit of your code can help others to help you!:)

Comment: @tashakori Thank you for your guidance. For sure, in 6 hours I will.

Comment: You realise that 2 Telegram bots cannot talk to each other right?